# How can I get the MediaStore ID of a media file if all I have is the DocumentFile Uri so I can get a thumbnail or album art?

Tags: android

I'm able to get the album art or thumbnails of videos out of the `MediaStore` using the video ID, and I'm able to get the album art by appending the album ID to `content://media/external/audio/albumart`. To get those IDs I use a `ContentResolver` query for which I pass the file path (/.../.../file.mp4 for example), but what if all I have is the content `Uri` (content://..../file.mp4 for example).

How can I get those MediaStore IDs from the `Uri` or `DocumentFile`?

Edit:
This is how I get the IDs.

For Audio:

```
Cursor cursor = contentResolver.query(uri, columns, MediaStore.MediaColumns.DATA + " LIKE ?", new String[]{url}, null);
....
long albumID = cursor.getLong(1);
```

For Video:

```
Cursor cursor = contentResolver.query(uri, columns, MediaStore.Video.VideoColumns.DATA + " LIKE ?", new String[]{url}, null);
....
long fileID = cursor.getLong(0);
```

For Images it is similar to video but with `MediaStore.Images.ImageColumns.DATA`

Edit:

To further clarify, I get the `DocumentFile` `Uri` by using the SAF file picker. On the `onActivityResult` I'm given a `Uri` for a file. If this file is a media file, I would like to find a way to get the thumbnail of that file from the `MediaStore`.

Comment: `I'm able to get the album art or thumbnails of videos out of the MediaStore using the video ID,...` Well all begins with how you obtained that ID and you omitted that info.

Comment: Updated my question with those details.

Comment: Your scenario is still pretty unclear to me. I cannot follow you in other words. Please write a more complete post. Step by step. And how did you obtain a Document file uri? And of what? All pretty unclear. And what shout that have to fo with earlier obtained media store id's ?

Comment: It is a `DocumentFile` of a media file. You obtain `DocumentFile` `Uri` addresses by using the SAF file picker.

Comment: Yes i know that. And a saf uri can be converted to a media store uri on Android 11 devices.

Comment: That would probably solve my problem. How is that conversion done?

Comment: Something like MediaStore.getUri(safuri); Or however the function is called. That you didnt already find it... And the reverse is there too.

Answer (score 0):

I think you don't require media id for the thumbnail. Just load thumbnails via [Glide](https://github.com/bumptech/glide) library by passing uri in load method.

```
RequestManager requestManager = Glide.with(this);
requestManager.load(uri)
                        .listener(new RequestListener<Drawable>() {
                            @Override
                            public boolean onLoadFailed(@Nullable GlideException e, Object model, Target<Drawable> target, boolean isFirstResource) {
                                return false;
                            }

                            @Override
                            public boolean onResourceReady(Drawable resource, Object model, Target<Drawable> target, DataSource dataSource, boolean isFirstResource) {
                                                                   return false;
                            }
                        })
                        .submit();
```